# Maximum SDK version for "aapt dump badging"

Tags: android, apk, android-resources, aapt

`aapt dump badging` command outputs the icon of the Android application.

However, after [adaptive icons](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive.html) were introduced in Android 8, `aapt` outputs only *xml* icons from the `mipmap-anydpi-v26` directory; *png* icons from the lower SDK versions are not printed.

I've tried `aapt dump badging application.apk --max-res-version 25` – no luck.

Is there any way to get the application icons from the lower SDK versions via `aapt dump badging`?